# Replace words by synonyms in all word's occurrences of all rows using SQL of ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I've created file with this content as [synonyms extension in ClickHouse](https://%20I%27ve%20created%20file%20with%20this%20content%20as%20synonyms%20extension%20%20%20%7C%20canonic%20%7C%20alias1%20%7C%20alias2%7C%20%20%20%7C:-------%20%7C:------%20%7C:-----%20%7C%20%20%7C%20espacio%20%7C%20esp###acio%20%7C%20otro###despacio%7C%20%20%7C%20classeAAAA%20%7C%20classe-a%20%7C%20classea%7C%20%20%7C%20classeCCCC%20%7C%20classe-c%20%7C%20clasec%7C%20%20%20When%20I%20execute%20SQL%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20synonyms(%27synonymsFuncion%27,%27classe-a%27)%20%20settings%20allow_experimental_nlp_functions=1%20%20Result%20works%20fine%20%20%7Csynonyms(%27synonymsFuncion%27,%20%27classe-a%27)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7C:-----------------------------------%7C%20%5B%27classeAAAA%27,%27classe-a%27,%27classea%27%5D%7C%20%20The%20main%20table%20contains%20rows%20in%20text%20format%20%20%7C%20URL%20%7C%20%7C:---%20%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20the%20fist%20phrase%20contains%20classe-a%20and%20classe-c%20,%20the%20result%20must%20replace%20all%20classe-a%20and%20classe-c%20to%20synonimes%20in%20sinonimos%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20second%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-c,%20classe-c%20again%20and%20classe-c%20one%20more%20time%20%7C%20%7C%20This%20last%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-a,%20classe-z%20again%20and%20classe-c%20%7C%20%20I%20want%20replace%20all%20occurrences%20to%20some%20expecifics%20words%20(which%20are%20defined%20using%20%27WITH%27)%20to%20its%20synonims%20in%20all%20rows%20results%20%20%20My%20sql%20is%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WITH%20%5B%27classe-a%27,%27other%20text%27,%27classe-c%27%5D%20AS%20replaaceWords%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20%20arrayJoin(arrayMap((y)-%3EreplaceAll(url,y,synonyms(%27synonymsFuncion%27,y)%5B1%5D),replaaceWords))%20as%20results%20from%20(select%20arrayJoin(%5B%27This%20is%20the%20fist%20phrase%20contains%20classe-a%20and%20classe-c%20,%20the%20result%20must%20replace%20all%20classe-a%20and%20classe-c%20to%20synonimes%20in%20sinonimos%27,%27This%20is%20second%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-c,%20classe-c%20again%20and%20classe-c%20one%20more%20time%27,%27This%20last%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-a,%20classe-z%20again%20and%20classe-c%20%27%5D)%20as%20url)%20settings%20allow_experimental_nlp_functions=1%20%20where%20%60%27replaaceWords%27%60%20are%20the%20words%20to%20replace%20for%20each%20text%20matched%20of%20each%20row%20using%20synonimes.%20%20%20Results%20from%20this%20SQL%20are%20%20%7C%20results%20%7C%20%7C--%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20the%20fist%20phrase%20contains%20classeAAAA%20and%20classe-c%20,%20the%20result%20must%20replace%20all%20classeAAAA%20and%20classe-c%20to%20synonimes%20in%20sinonimos%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20the%20fist%20phrase%20contains%20classe-a%20and%20classe-c%20,%20the%20result%20must%20replace%20all%20classe-a%20and%20classe-c%20to%20synonimes%20in%20sinonimos%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20the%20fist%20phrase%20contains%20classe-a%20and%20classeCCCC%20,%20the%20result%20must%20replace%20all%20classe-a%20and%20classeCCCC%20to%20synonimes%20in%20sinonimos%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20second%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-c,%20classe-c%20again%20and%20classe-c%20one%20more%20time%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20second%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-c,%20classe-c%20again%20and%20classe-c%20one%20more%20time%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20second%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classeCCCC,%20classeCCCC%20again%20and%20classeCCCC%20one%20more%20time%7C%20%7C%20This%20last%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classeAAAA,%20classe-z%20again%20and%20classe-c%7C%20%7C%20This%20last%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-a,%20classe-z%20again%20and%20classe-c%7C%20%7C%20This%20last%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20classe-a,%20classe-z%20again%20and%20classeCCCC%7C%20%20**My%20result%20desired**:%20%20%7C%20URL%20%7C%20%7C:---%20%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20the%20fist%20phrase%20contains%20***classeAAAA***%20and%20***classeCCCC***%20,%20the%20result%20must%20replace%20all%20***classeAAAA***%20and%20***classeCCCC***%20to%20synonimes%20in%20sinonimos%7C%20%7C%20This%20is%20second%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20***classeCCCC***,%20***classeCCCC***%20again%20and%20***classeCCCC***%20one%20more%20time%20%7C%20%7C%20This%20last%20phrase%20contains%20classe-z%20and%20***classeAAAA***,%20classe-z%20again%20and%20***classeCCCC***%20%7C%20%20Thanks!!)

| canonic | alias1 | alias2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| espacio | esp###acio | otro###despacio |
| classeAAAA | classe-a | classea |
| classeCCCC | classe-c | clasec |

When I execute SQL

```
select synonyms('synonymsFuncion','classe-a')  settings allow_experimental_nlp_functions=1
```

Result works fine

| synonyms('synonymsFuncion', 'classe-a') |
| --- |
| ['classeAAAA','classe-a','classea'] |

The main table contains rows in text format

| URL |
| --- |
| This is the fist phrase contains classe-a and classe-c , the result must replace all classe-a and classe-c to synonimes in sinonimos |
| This is second phrase contains classe-z and classe-c, classe-c again and classe-c one more time |
| This last phrase contains classe-z and classe-a, classe-z again and classe-c |

I want replace all occurrences to some expecifics words (which are defined using 'WITH') to its synonims in all rows results

My sql is

```
WITH ['classe-a','other text','classe-c'] AS replaaceWords 
select  arrayJoin(arrayMap((y)->replaceAll(url,y,synonyms('synonymsFuncion',y)[1]),replaaceWords)) as results from (select arrayJoin(['This is the fist phrase contains classe-a and classe-c , the result must replace all classe-a and classe-c to synonimes in sinonimos','This is second phrase contains classe-z and classe-c, classe-c again and classe-c one more time','This last phrase contains classe-z and classe-a, classe-z again and classe-c ']) as url) settings allow_experimental_nlp_functions=1
```

where `'replaaceWords'` are the words to replace for each text matched of each row using synonimes.

Results from this SQL are

| results |
| --- |
| This is the fist phrase contains classeAAAA and classe-c , the result must replace all classeAAAA and classe-c to synonimes in sinonimos |
| This is the fist phrase contains classe-a and classe-c , the result must replace all classe-a and classe-c to synonimes in sinonimos |
| This is the fist phrase contains classe-a and classeCCCC , the result must replace all classe-a and classeCCCC to synonimes in sinonimos |
| This is second phrase contains classe-z and classe-c, classe-c again and classe-c one more time |
| This is second phrase contains classe-z and classe-c, classe-c again and classe-c one more time |
| This is second phrase contains classe-z and classeCCCC, classeCCCC again and classeCCCC one more time |
| This last phrase contains classe-z and classeAAAA, classe-z again and classe-c |
| This last phrase contains classe-z and classe-a, classe-z again and classe-c |
| This last phrase contains classe-z and classe-a, classe-z again and classeCCCC |

**My result desired**:

| URL |
| --- |
| This is the fist phrase contains ***classeAAAA*** and ***classeCCCC*** , the result must replace all ***classeAAAA*** and ***classeCCCC*** to synonimes in sinonimos |
| This is second phrase contains classe-z and ***classeCCCC***, ***classeCCCC*** again and ***classeCCCC*** one more time |
| This last phrase contains classe-z and ***classeAAAA***, classe-z again and ***classeCCCC*** |

Thanks!!